# Producing a softmax on two channels in Tensorflow and Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, softmax

My network's penultimate layer has shape `(U, C)` where `C` is the number of channels. I'd like to apply softmax function across each channel separately.

For example, if `U=2` and `C=3`, and the layer produces `[ [1 2 3], [10 20 30] ]`, I'd like the output to do `softmax(1, 2, 3)` for channel 0 and `softmax(10, 20, 30)` for the channel 1.

Is there a way I can do this with Keras? I'm using TensorFlow as the backend.

### UPDATE

Please also explain how to ensure that the loss is the sum of both cross entropies, and how I can verify that? (That is, I don't want the optimizer to only train for loss on one of the softmax, but rather the sum of each's cross entropy loss).  The model uses Keras's built in `categorical_crossentropy` for loss.

Comment: "U=2 and C=3" is inconsistent `[ [1 10] [2 20] [3 30] ]`, since it is an array with shape `(3, 2)` and not `(2, 3)`. Please edit your post and make it consistent.

Comment: @today I've never mastered the way numpy displays arrays as strings.  U=2 and C=3 is correct; if you can edit to the correct numpy string, I'd appreciate it; if not, tell me what it is and I'll edit myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a `Lambda` layer and use the `softmax` function from the backend with a desired axis to compute the softmax over that axis:

```
from keras import backend as K
from keras.layers import Lambda

soft_out = Lambda(lambda x: K.softmax(x, axis=my_desired_axis))(input_tensor)
```

---

**Update:** A numpy array with N dimension would have a shape of `(d1, d2, d3, ..., dn)`. Each one of them is called an axis. So the first axis (i.e. `axis=0`) has dimension `d1`, the second axis (i.e. `axis=1`) has dimension `d2` and so on. Further, the most common case of an array is a 2D array or a matrix which has a shape of `(m, n)`, i.e. `m` rows (i.e. `axis=0`) and `n` columns (i.e. `axis=1`). Now when we specify an axis for performing an operation, it means that the operation should be computed over that axis. Let me make this more clear by examples:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
>>> a
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])

>>> a.shape
(3, 4)   # three rows and four columns

>>> np.sum(a, axis=0)  # compute the sum over the rows (i.e. for each column)
array([12, 15, 18, 21])

>>> np.sum(a, axis=1)  # compute the sum over the columns (i.e. for each row)
array([ 6, 22, 38])

>>> np.sum(a, axis=-1) # axis=-1 is equivalent to the last axis (i.e. columns)
array([ 6, 22, 38])
```

Now, in your example, the same thing holds for computing softmax function. You must first determine over which axis you want to compute the softmax and then specify that using `axis` argument. Further, note that softmax by default is applied on the last axis (i.e. `axis=-1`) so if you want to compute it over the last axis you don't need the Lambda layer above. Just use the [`Activation`](https://keras.io/activations/) layer instead:

```
from keras.layers import Activation

soft_out = Activation('softmax')(input_tensor)
```

---

**Update 2:** There is also another way of doing this using `Softmax` layer:

```
from keras.layers import Softmax

soft_out = Softmax(axis=desired_axis)(input_tensor)
```

Comment: @SRobertJames I have updated my answer. Please take a look.

Comment: Very helpful; Q updated accordingly.  Can you please address the last remaining point, that is, how do we ensure we are computing cross entropy loss on each entry of `axis -1` independently, with the loss to optimize being the **sum** of both cross entropies?

Comment: @SRobertJames It depends on what the loss function is. Do you use a custom loss function or the built-in `categorical_crossentropy` function?

Comment: The build in `categorical_crossentropy`

Comment: @SRobertJames `categorical_crossentropy` is applied on the last axis (i.e. `axis=-1`) by default. As for the errors, edit your question and include the code and the error you get.

Comment: Phenomenal answer, very much appreciated!  The error was my mistake; I resolved it and deleted the comment.

Answer (score 2):

use functional api for multiple outputs. https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/

```
input = Input(...)
...
t = some_tensor
t0 = t0[:,:,0]
t1 = t0[:,:,1]
soft0 = Softmax(output_shape)(t0)
soft1 = Softmax(output_shape)(t1)
outputs = [soft0,soft1]
model = Model(inputs=input, outputs=outputs)
model.compile(...)
model.fit(x_train, [y_train0, ytrain1], epoch = 10, batch_size=32)
```